# Is this the optimal cypher for returning every node of a subtree?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph of a tree structure (well no, more of a DAG because i can have multiple parents) and need to be able to write queries that return all results in a flat list, starting at a particular node(s) and down.

I've reduced one of my use cases to this simple example.  In the ascii representation here, n's are my nodes and I've appended their id. p is a permission in my auth system, but all that is pertinent to the question is that it marks the spot from which I need to recurse downwards to collect nodes which should be returned by the query.

- There can be multiple root nodes related to p's
- The roots, such as n3 below, should be contained in the results, as well as the children
- The relationship depth is unbounded.

Graph:

```
   n1
  ^ ^
 /   \
n2    n3<--p
     ^ ^
    /   \
   n4    n5
  ^
 /
n6
```

If it's helpful, here's the cypher I ran to throw together this quick example:

```
CREATE path=(n1:n{id:1})<-[:HAS_PARENT]-(n2:n{id:2}), 
      (n1)<-[:HAS_PARENT]-(n3:n{id:3})<-[:HAS_PARENT]-(n4:n{id:4}),
      (n3)<-[:HAS_PARENT]-(n5:n{id:5}),
      (n4)<-[:HAS_PARENT]-(n6:n{id:6})
MATCH (n{id:3})
CREATE (:p)-[:IN]->(n)
```

Here is the current best query I have:

```
MATCH (n:n)<--(:p)
WITH collect (n) as parents, (n) as n
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS_PARENT*]->(n)
WITH collect(c) as children, (parents) as parents
UNWIND (parents+children) as tree
RETURN tree
```

This returns the correct set of results, and unlike some previous attempts I made which did not use any collect/unwind, the results come back as a single column of data as desired.

Is this the most optimal way of making this type of query?  It is surprisingly more complex than I thought the simple scenario called for.  I tried some queries where I combined the roots ("parents" in my query) with the "children" using a UNION clause, but I could not find a way to do so without repeating the query for the relationship with p.  In my real world queries, that's a much more expensive operation which i've reduced down here for the example, so I cannot run it more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might suit your needs:

```
MATCH (c)-[:HAS_PARENT*0..]->(root:n)<--(:p)
RETURN root, COLLECT(c) AS tree
```

Each result row will contain a distinct `root` node and a collection if its tree nodes (including the root node).

Comment: I don't need to return the separate root or perform the collect(), but this gives me what I need.  The concepts I was missing were: a * with no number defaults to 1 instead of 0, and that a path length of 0 between c and root logically means that c is root.  Thanks!